# Java FX arithmetic expression in a button

Tags: java, exception, javafx

hi i want to do a button that takes two input fields and trying to do the following :

1. chick if it's a number .(so it can devide the two numbers)
2. i can't devide any number by zero .
   and showing that it's a arithmetic expression .
   so any help ?
   the code is blow ::
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1gdJ.jpg)

code ::

```
b4.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent ex) -> {
String Num1 = tf4.getText();
String Num2 = tf8.getText();


if(Num1.matches("^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") && Num2.matches("^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
    
    
    try {
        
        double Num1f = Double.parseDouble(Num1);
        double Num2f = Double.parseDouble(Num2);
     double     result =(Num2f / Num1f);
     
   valf4.setText(String.valueOf(result));

     
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("ArithmeticException");
        valf4.setText("You can't do that !");
    }
} else {
    
}
```

});

and it show infinity
not what i expected as i did in catch area

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: it should works but it shows infinity

Comment: not what i wanted to show in the catch area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic in Java does not throw exceptions for division by zero; it evaluates to one of the special values in the `Double` class (`Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` or `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`).

Instead of catching the exception, you can just test if the denominator is zero, or test if the result is infinite:

```
b4.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent ex) -> {

    String num1 = tf4.getText();
    String num2 = tf8.getText();
    
    
    if(num1.matches("^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?") && num2.matches("^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
        
        
        double num1f = Double.parseDouble(num1);
        double num2f = Double.parseDouble(num2);
        double result = num2f / num1f;
        
        if (Double.isInfinite(result)) { 
            valf4.setText("You can't do that !");
        } else {
            valf4.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        }
    } else {
        
    }

});
```